# <a> tag click event won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html(+razor) :

```
<div id = "years" class="btn-group btn-group-justified timeline">
    <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.Year</a>
    <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year</a>
    <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year</a>
</div>
```

I simply want to have use these as buttons and something to happen on click. Therefore I have the following jquery, which won't work :

```
$(".btn a").click(function () {
        console.log('click');

            var txt = $(this).text();
            console.log(txt);
            alert(txt);


    });
```

I simply want to have the value inbetween the  on click. 
Right now, when I click one of the buttons, nothing happens. Neither I get 'click' written on the console, nor i get an alert with the text in the tag. Can someone help make this work?

Comment: try like this `$("a.btn")`

Comment: binding click event handler within another ? what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this code**

**Example #1:**

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "years" class="btn-group btn-group-justified timeline">
    <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.Year</a><br><br>
    <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year</a><br><br>
    <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year</a>
</div>
<script>
$("a.btn").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 console.log(this);
alert("click");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Example #2:**

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "years" class="btn-group btn-group-justified timeline">
    <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.Year</a><br><br>
    <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year</a><br><br>
    <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year</a>
</div>
<script>
  // without a
$(".btn").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 console.log(this);
alert("click");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Example #3:**

```html
 <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id = "years" class="btn-group btn-group-justified timeline">
        <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.Year</a><br><br>
        <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year</a><br><br>
        <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year</a>
    </div>
    <script>
     
    $("#years a").click(function(e){
      console.log(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("click");
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(".btn a")` is looking for `<a>` tags that are descendents of `.btn` class. That is not what you have

Just use the inner listener and get rid of the outer one. It is not a good practice to create event listeners inside other event handlers unless you really have a good reason and know what you are doing

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="years" class="btn-group btn-group-justified timeline">
        <a href="#@DateTime.Now.Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.Year</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="#@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="#@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#years a").click(function(e) {
            console.log(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("click");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does what i was trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Your enclosing div does not have a class of .btn so your jquery selector won't find anything. Try:

```
$(".btn-group a").click(...)
```